# Where can i use $('#elementId').trigger('contentUpdated') and how?

Tags: frontend, requirejs, magento-2.1.3

I have added my **script** as follows in template :

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*":{
        "Vendor_Module/js/myscript":{
            "baseUrl": "<?php echo $quickshopHelper->getBaseUrl() ?>",
            "qsLabel": "<?php echo $quickshopHelper->getQuickShopLabel() ?>",
            "itemClass": "<?php echo (!empty($itemClass))?$itemClass:"" ?>",
            "target": "<?php echo (!empty($target))?$target:".product-item-info"; ?>",
            "autoAddButtons":<?php echo ($autoAddButtons==1)?"true":"false" ?>
            }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have called the template in **default.xml** cause I want it everywhere in frontend. Its working fine on **page load** but on certain pages when **ajax call** is made, my script doesn't work. I tried on the same template to **trigger** mage using below code but it's not working.

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {

        $('.main').trigger('contentUpdated');
});
</script>
```

And yes the **selector** is in another module and not my template. I have almost referred everything I could find related to this **declarative notation** but could not find the solution yet.